# Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'null'.ts(2322) error after updating ionic

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, typeerror

I am using the below code for side menu more than two years till ionic version 5
now after updating ionic to 6.20.6 and angular 15^ I am getting the below error at

> else {
> **this.showLevel1 = idx;**
> }

Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'null'.ts(2322)

```
export class AppComponent {
  public appPages: any;
  showLevel1 = null;
  showLevel2 = null;
   @ViewChildren(IonRouterOutlet) routerOutlets: QueryList<IonRouterOutlet>;

  
 
  clearLevel() {
    this.showLevel1 = null;
    this.showLevel2 = null;
  //  this.showLevel3 = null;
  }
  toggleLevel1(idx: string) {
    if (this.isLevel1Shown(idx)) {
      this.showLevel1 = null;
    } else {
      this.showLevel1 = idx;
    }
    
  }
  isLevel1Shown(idx: string) {
    
    return this.showLevel1 === idx;
  }
```

Comment: The type is being inferred as a literal null. Add types e.g. `showLevel1: string | null = null`

Comment: Exactly, it works for me without error thank you @AndrewAllen

Answer (score 0):

Latest ionic was embedded with string typing. Assign empty string, if you are going to use a variable/Member variable as string.
Eg.,

```
showLevel1:string="";
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the suggestion given by -[[Andru Alen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4711754/andrew-allen)][1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4711754/andrew-allen)
as comment in my post and it is working fine for me.
Below given the modified code:

```
   public appPages: any;
  showLevel1: string | null = null;
  showLevel2: string | null = null;
   @ViewChildren(IonRouterOutlet)
  routerOutlets!: QueryList<IonRouterOutlet>;

  
  constructor(
    private platform: Platform,

    private router: Router,
    private data: DataService
  ) {
    
   // this.backButtonEvent();
    this.data.getData().subscribe((resp) => {
   //   console.log(resp);
      this.appPages = resp;
    });
   
  }

  clearLevel() {
    this.showLevel1 = null;
    this.showLevel2 = null;
  //  this.showLevel3 = null;
  }
  toggleLevel1(idx: string) {
    if (this.isLevel1Shown(idx)) {
      this.showLevel1 = null;
    } else {
      this.showLevel1 = idx;
    }
    
  }`enter code here`
  isLevel1Shown(idx: string) {
    
    return this.showLevel1 === idx;`d`
  }`enter code here`
```